# JavaScript Connection of Newsletter Plugins

Tags: javascript, frontend, newsletter

I would like to transfer data between two platforms. Unfortunately, the second platform does not offer me the possibility to process a service. However, it offers a plug-in that I can insert on the first platform. This PlugIn has already set up the data transfer.
It is a newsletter entry field. Unfortunately, I cannot use the field on platform 2 in the frontend because it cannot be edited UI-wise.

1. Own homepage - platform 1
2. PlugIn from platform 2

I came up with the following approach:
I use a newsletter entry field (1) on my website and would like this to be linked to another newsletter entry field (plugin) (2).

This means that when the user makes entries in field (1), the same entries should appear in field (2).
Likewise, when a checkbox (1) is pressed, the same checkbox (2) should be pressed.
As soon as the "Submit" button (1) is pressed, the button (2) should also be pressed.
Can anyone help me with the search terms I need to look for, recommend tutorials or explain what the code should look like?
[image: Image for clarification]

Comment: you've shown an image of a webpage. What does your question have to do with javascript?

Comment: I can do code suggestions with Javascript.

Comment: OK, suggest some code

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the field on platform 2 cannot be edited UI-wise. Therefore, what you want to do is impossible as it involve editing the UI on the field on platform 2. However, there is usually other ways to work around the issue you're facing.

The most optimal solution would be to use a public API to platform 2. Whenever user click on the submit button on your page, your site can make use of the public API to submit the request and return the result.

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. To understand it right - I create an API sending the data to an another platform, which sends the data back to my platform 1 to insert them into the Platform 2 plugin, right?

Comment: You use the API from platform 2 which should be provided to you if they allow you to insert it into your site. If such API is unavailable to you, then it'll be impossible to do, e.g. **you can't implement your own website for other people to sign in to google because google don't allow this**. However, you can use google api to let the google signin page pop up and let you sign in from google but not inserting the google(platform 2) signin page into your website (platform 1).

Comment: As platform 2 provides a plug in, you should look for public API for platform 2. Hopefully it is available or what you want to do is simply impossible or require extremely high effort to do.